# What is a simple way to brighten textures mapped to a quad in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es, colors

I'm displaying 2D sprites that are built using multiple textures (with transparency) applied to quads.  I have enabled the color array for glDrawArrays and know how to use this to change the ratio of each color and to dim the textures (ie. reducing all colors the same amount).

This is all done using the premultiplied alpha and the following:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
```

Is there a simple way to brighten a texture as well?

I tried using GL_ADD, but this causes the entire quad to become visible (ie. pixels that were previously transparent are not anymore).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite easy: draw another quad over the region you want brightened, with that overlay quad using

```
glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_DST_COLOR, GL10.GL_ONE);
```

which [effectively](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glBlendFunc.html) means you take the underlying color (dst, GL_ONE) as it is, and add another fraction of the same color (src, GL10.GL_DST_COLOR).

The fraction you add is specified by the color of the quad, so you can now tweak the brightness by setting the overlay quad's vertex colors to {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f} (no brightening) to {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f} ('doubling' the brightness). Of course you can increase individual colors' brightness by tweaking the factors as well.

Good luck!

Cheers, Aert.

Comment: Won't this cause the fully transparent pixels to stop being transparent?

Comment: No, it doesn't change the sprite you're drawing! You're just overlaying a brightening quad over it.

Comment: I'm currently using a different blend function to keep my premultiplied alpha textures from having artifacts (GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA).  I assume that I would change the BlendFunc to what you recommend and then back to keep my existing behavior.  I'm using glDrawArrays to reduce draw calls, so I have to understand how this works with that style of OGL-ES coding.  Any tips or examples of what you recommend mixed with glDrawArrays (or glDrawElements) would be appreciated as I've not found this elsewhere.  Regardless, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes, you will have to do a separate draw call for those overlay quads as you have to switch the state machine in between. So you would have (1) glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA), (2) glDrawElements(sprites) (3) glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE) (4) glDrawElements(brightening quads). Wouldn't worry about a few extra draw calls, unless you have tens of them. Alternatively, you can use multi-texturing, see [http://softwareprodigy.blogspot.com/2009/08/multitexturing-on-opengl-es.html] for a good example. This achieves the same with one quad, but is a bit trickier to set up. Cheers!